# ComponentDidMount work from one screen but does not work from the other - React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was reading a bit and it seems that the reason why ComponentDidMount seem to not activate, is because it's already on the stack navigator. For that, we have to use the addListener with 'didFocus'.

Suppose I have 3 screens A,B,C. What I don't understand is why when my app is loaded on screen B, componentDidMount works implicitly (I don't need 'didFocus') on screen B from C->B but not work from A->B

```
ComponentDidMount() 
{
   //ComponentDidMount Located in Screen B

   execute code1.  //works from C->B, Does not work from A->B

   this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus'{
      execute code2.    //Works for both
   })
}
```

The stack navigator looks like the this

```
createStackNavigator({
FriendsArea: {
    screen:B,
    navigationOptions:{
      header:null
    }
  },
  HostArea: {
    screen:C,
    navigigationOptions:{
      header:null
    }
  },
  Profile: {
    screen:A,
    navigationOptions:{
      header:null
    }
  },
})
```

Could someone help? I can clarify some more if need, thank you.

Comment: Can you post the creation of the stack navigator?

Comment: Screen A, B, C are in order?

Comment: @fxbayuanggara I included the stack navigator

Comment: @KushalDesai Please see the added code for the screen order.

Comment: Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is matters in stack navigator, you should arrange the stack like this:

```
createStackNavigator({
FriendsArea: {
  screen:A,
    navigationOptions:{
      header:null
    }
  },
  HostArea: {
    screen:B,
    navigigationOptions:{
      header:null
    }
  },
  Profile: {
    screen:C,
    navigationOptions:{
      header:null
    }
  },
})
```

A = first page, B = next page after A, C = next page after B

Your problem happened because the B component already called the componentDidMount method while creating the A component so that you have to call the didFocus listener which is usually used to execute the code when we are navigating back from other page.

Comment: this is still not working for me unfortunately. Although the pages are in order, navigating from profile to FriendsArea still do not require 'didFocus'. I would like for it to require 'didFocus'